# How to Tell No MOT Advisory Notes?

Tags: service, testing

In the UK, the MOT test may contain advisory notes but as far as I understand these are optional. One can also check the MOT history of a vehicle through Gov.UK web site. However I don't understand by looking at that if the car really has no advisory notes, or the owner preferred not including them in the report. Is there a way to tell that, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner does not post the reports or results of the mot on the gov website - it comes from the testing station and the tester. The tester may be able to exercise their judgement about posting advisories or not, but the standard report will be complete.

Comment: Somehow I've had the impression that they were optional and the owner could choose not to include them. I can't find any source to confirm this now and apparently I was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: This is my understanding - two good friends of mine still in the motor trade have their mot qualifications and I have never seen them discuss the report with a customer. Well apart from this bit is broken and it will cost ......